# Can't type into Android Studio's built in terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

Don't know since when, but I was off work for a few days, and now Android Studio is wont to not let me type into the built in terminal.

I use Android Studio on my HP laptop with Windows 10 on top of it.

Here's a screenshot, as I click on it the cursor gets highlighted and starts blinking as usual but typing into it doesn't work anymore.

[image: Android Studio terminal]

Well I have tried

- adding terminals,
- removing Terminals,
- deleting AS data, and
- even reinstalling AS completely

If anyone has got a solution, please assist.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is an issue on Windows 10. To fix it, open a command prompt window (`cmd.exe`), then right click the title, and open `Properties`. Check `Use legacy console`, and it should go back to working (might need to restart Android Studio).

Comment: Man, you just saved a life! It was Windows 10 all this time and I was going completely insane over AS. How come this thought never came into my mind.

Comment: Thanks @RogueBaneling

Comment: @abhi SrS? chill down, in the worse case you could just add thw ADB folder to the OS local variable and access directly from the CMD.

Comment: Hii Man 
i am not able see "Use legacy console " and i am using window 7  please help me

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know that, need this solution also for Windows 8.1

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution does not work. I can´t type at all. Any help?

Comment: DId u guys find answer for this in windows 7

Answer (score 1):

This happens with Windows 10.I also experienced the same issue and Resolved with the following steps.

- Step 1 [image: Check Use Legacy Console in CMD Prompt]
- Step 2 [image: Restart Android Studio]
- Step 3 [image: Now try in Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a poweruser and you don't to use the old console.
You can add the path of android tools to OS 'PATH' variable, and then you could access from the CMD.
Cumbersome but works.

Comment: And what about the developers who don't want to use the 20 years old console? Do you have an 'alternative' for them? If you are a pure android dev you probably don't need to use win console, but I'm using more tech which require me to use win console from time to time, and when I do so, I want to have the new version.

Answer (score 0):

It  is still not working for me. Did both path setting and old console ,restarted studio ;still I cant type in the terminal window of android studio; however on some occasions,if I remember correctly , it has worked though - using Windows 10 + studio 1.4.1 .

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and running as admin fixed this (drove me crazy).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this directory
**C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools** and copy file location, then you should paste this directory on Environment variables, which I mentioned on this image:

[Click edit and add new section there for pasting directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJMfJ.png)

**After all of these actions, finally you can restart your Android Studio IDE and enjoy the terminal on Android Studio**