# Trouble Typing in Android Studio 4.0 Terminal with Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, terminal, windows-10

Very new to programming and first time question on stackoverflow. Running Windows 10 on a new Dell laptop. I just downloaded Android Studio 4.0 (July 2020) and am super excited to start using it however I am having a lot of trouble typing in the terminal. When I switch views to any xml or java tab I cannot not type in the terminal. the cursor moves around and does different things when trying to type. It even starts to delete code sometimes. After hitting the keyboard about 20-30 times, it starts working fine until i switch to a new java or xml file and i have to repeat the process. It is really frustrating for a beginner.

I can copy text from the internet or notepad and paste it using my mouse with no issues but I cannot use control+v to paste.

Everything works just fine in Eclipse.

I read the [stack overflow response from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954437/cant-type-into-android-studios-built-in-terminal/33496379) but changing command prompt to legacy console did not resolve the issue.

I uploaded a [Youtube Video showing my issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BS6xYDsuj8&feature=youtu.be) if that helps at all.

I assume it's still an issue with windows 10 compatibility with intellij but not sure. Is there any work around for this? is there another console i can use that would bypass whatever isn't working with my windows 10 console? It's hard enough trying to learn java AND android studio from scratch but then also having to paste everything from notepad is just ridiculous.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to disable IdeaVim plugin.